# HttpWebRequest POST Login error 405

Tags: c#, stream, httpwebrequest, seek

Im trying to make a small login system but i have this problem that when the project runs on VS2010 it says :

```
The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.
```

Heres my code:

```
 //Our URL
        string uri = "https://************************/ValidateUsername";
        //Our postvars
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( "username=user" );

        //Initialization
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
        request.Headers.Add("Language", "es-MX");
        request.Headers.Add("Application", "-------------------");
        request.Headers.Add("Version", "1.0");

        //Our method is POST, otherway buffer would be useless
        request.Method = "POST";

        //We use form contentType, for the postvars
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        //The lenght of the content its set by postvars (buffer) lenght
        request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;

        //We open a stream for writing the postvars
        Stream PostData = request.GetRequestStream();
        //Now we write, and afterwards, we close.
        PostData.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

When i hover the pointer over "PostData" and then i go to the length and position attributes, i can read :

```
Length = 'PostData.Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
base {System.SystemException} = {"This stream does not support seek operations."}
```

im not sure if this is the real problem, but im trying to give the mos of information possible.

```
        PostData.Close();

        //Get the response Handle
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        //lets show info about the response
        Console.WriteLine("Estatus de la respuesta:" + response.StatusCode);
        Console.WriteLine("Servidor : " + response.Server);

        //Now we read the response (the string), and output it
        //Stream answer = response.GetResponseStream();
        //StreamReader _answer = new StreamReader(answer);
        //Console.WriteLine("Respuesta: " + _answer.ReadToEnd());
```

At some forum i read that maybe the "_answer.ReadToEnd()" could be the problem but even thought i commented , the problem still arises.

Im doing this so i can try it later on windows phone, dont know if im wasting my time , because they are not related.

I hope someone can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting.  The server should only really give a 405 response if the http endpoint you specify does not allow POST.  Are you sure POST is supported?? If so, try hitting that endpoint with POST using curl from the commandline, or via something like Poster for Firefox?  Try `curl -i -X POST -d 'BlahBlahBlah'` and check your response.

Comment: You could also use HTTP tracer (for example Fiddler) to see the response. It might contain additional information why it failed.

Comment: I checked the server via Poster and it didn't accept post, so now im angry. Thanks a lot.